# How to join primary partition into physical volume

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm

I have a hard disk with this information :

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1c312bd6

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *      4198400 314576895 310378496   148G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       314576896 976769023 662192128 315.8G 83 Linux
```

I want to create physical volume with a new volume group on this HDD and join this two primary partitions to that volume group **without lose data** .

**In simple word :** Migrate normal partitions to LVM without lose data .

How can do that ?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: @mah454: because it's not a *programming* question - please see: [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Do both partitions contain data? If so, you're probably stuck. I'm not aware of any non-destructive method of switching from a plain filesystem to an LVM PV.

If you only have data on sdb1 or you have some way of preserving whatever data you have on sdb2, you can `pvcreate -> vgcreate -> lvcreate` sdb2 in isolation. Mount that single partition LV somewhere and copy the contents from sdb1 over to the LV. Then, you can `pvcreate -> vgextend -> lvextend` to add sdb1 into your overall logical volume.